# How to safe connect to postgres with mulitple scripts

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have starting to learn how to code psycopg2 together with Python. what I do is that I have quite few scripts. Lets have an example where it can be up to 150 connections and as we know, we cannot have more than 100 connections connected at the same time. What I figure out is that whenever I want to do a database query/execution - I then connect to the database, do the execution and then close the database. However I do believe that opening and closing new connection are very expensive and should be longer-lived.

I have done something like this:

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION = {
    "host": "TEST",
    "database": "TEST",
    "user": "TEST",
    "password": "TEST"
}


def get_all_links(store):
    """
    Get all links from given store
    :param store:
    :return:
    """

    conn = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)

    sql_update_query = "SELECT id, link FROM public.store_items WHERE store = %s AND visible = %s;"

    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    try:

        data_tuple = (store, "yes")
        cursor.execute(sql_update_query, data_tuple)

        test_data = [{"id": links["id"], "link": links["link"]} for links in cursor]
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return test_data

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        cursor.close()
        conn.rollback()
        return 1



def get_all_stores():
    """
    Get all stores in database
    :return:
    """

    conn = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)

    sql_update_query = "SELECT store FROM public.store_config;"

    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    try:

        cursor.execute(sql_update_query)

        test_data = [stores["store"] for stores in cursor]

        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return test_data

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        cursor.close()
        conn.rollback()
        return 1
```

I wonder how can I make it as effective as possible where I can have alot of scripts connected to the database but still do not hit the max_connection issue?

I do forgot to add that the way im connecting is that I have multiple scripts etc:

```
test1.py
test2.py
test3.py
....
....
```

*every script runs for themselves*

where they all have a import `database.py` which has the following code that I have showed before.

UPDATE:

```
from psycopg2 import pool

threaded_postgreSQL_pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(1, 2,
                                                                user="test",
                                                                password="test",
                                                                host="test",
                                                                database="test")

if (threaded_postgreSQL_pool):
    print("Connection pool created successfully using ThreadedConnectionPool")
    

def get_all_stores():
    """
    Get all stores in database
    :return:
    """

    # Use getconn() method to Get Connection from connection pool
    ps_connection = threaded_postgreSQL_pool.getconn()

    sql_update_query = "SELECT store FROM public.store_config;"

    ps_cursor = ps_connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    try:

        ps_cursor.execute(sql_update_query)

        test_data = [stores["store"] for stores in ps_cursor]

        ps_cursor.close()

        threaded_postgreSQL_pool.putconn(ps_connection)
        print("Put away a PostgreSQL connection")

        return test_data

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        ps_cursor.close()
        ps_connection.rollback()
        return 1
```

Comment: See [pooling solutions](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/pgpool-vs-pgbouncer)

Comment: @clamp im not sure if this can be beneit if every script will import the database.py file, I might be wrong and misunderstood obviously but please correct me if im wrong

Comment: There are different options how connections can be handled. In general a pool makes connecting cheaper. See (https://www.pgbouncer.org/usage.html).

Comment: @clamp oh I see, I assume it is something I need to install in the same server/host where I connect to the DB in that case? Does that mean that my code is fine then? Or is it something i'm missing in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While opening and close database connections is not free, it is also not all that expensive when compared to starting up and stopping the python interpreter.  If all your scripts are running independently and briefly, that is probably the first thing you should fix.  You have to decide and describe how your scripts are getting scheduled and invoked before you can know how (and if) to use a connection pooler.

> and as we know, we cannot have more than 100 connections connected at the same time.

100 is the default setting for max_connections, but it is entirely configurable.  You can increase it if you want to.  If you refactor for performance, you should probably do so in a way that naturally means you don't need to raise max_connections.  But refactoring just because you don't want to raise max_connections is letting the tail wag the dog.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, establishing a database connection is expensive; therefore, you should use *connection pooling*. But there is no need to re-invent the wheel, since [psycopg2 has built-in connection pooling](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html):

Use a `psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool` or `psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool` (depending on whether you use threading or not) and use the `getconn()` and `putconn()` methods to grab or return a connection.

Comment: Hello Laurenz! I have now done a update in the thread if you could please look into it. Is it something like this you meant? However the problem I might think of when using this, still. What would actually happend if I have several scripts that is running by itself (by that I mean I start py test1.py, py test2.py, py test3.py ... up to 150). Will this still be count as 150 connected or how will this method then work?

Comment: Looks ok at first glance, but I don't really know Python. If you start many different instances of the Python interpreter, you will end up with many connection pools, and the purpose would be defeated. But if your application has multiple threads they will share a single connection pool, so do that.